# ambiguous in property names of object due to inner join in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I using following code for joining two tables in my controller

```
$clientdata = DB::table('clients')
 ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.id')->get();
```

In blade:

```
@foreach($clientdata as $clientdata)
<td>{{$clientdata->first_name(client)}}</td>
<td>{{$clientdata->last_name(client)}}</td>
<td>{{$clientdata->first_name(users)}}</td>
<td>{{$clientdata->last_name(users)}}</td>
@endforeach
```

but my both tables clients and users contains column of same name as `first_name` and `last_name`,  and i want to access `first_name` and `last_name` of both clients table and users table, so how can i do that

Comment: could you please add table designs

Comment: in my controller    $clientdata = DB::table('clients')
 ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.id')->get();     return view('index', compact("clientdata');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
$clientdata = DB::table('clients')
   ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.id')
   ->select(
       'users.first_name as users_first_name',
       'users.last_name as users_last_name',
       'clients.first_name as clients_first_name',
       'clients.last_name as clients_last_name',
   )
   ->get();
```

In your blade file:

```
@foreach($clientdata as $data)
<td>{{$data->users_first_name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->users_last_name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->clients_first_name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->clients_last_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: in my clients table, number of rows greater than users table row, hence it leaves that much rows from clients table, but i want whole clients table data and relative users table data if present how can i achieve it??

Answer (score 4):

I use always this solution

Lazy one :) (In case of high number of columns)

I select all columns in both tables (table.*), and I add my ambiguous columns with aliases (table.ambiguous_1 AS alias)

Example

```
$clientdata = DB::table('clients')
->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.id')
->select(
   'users.*',
   'clients.*',
   'users.first_name AS users_first_name',
   'users.last_name AS users_last_name',
   'clients.first_name AS clients_first_name',
   'clients.last_name AS clients_last_name',
)
->get();
```

In the blade I use the alias for ambiguous columns and orginal column name in others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
     DB::table('clients') ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.id')->select('clients*', DB::raw('clients as client_name'))->get();
```